For a Rectangular function, does the FT result in real numbers and the DFT result in complex numbers?
I was trying to do FT and DFT for a reactangular function that is 1 from (-T/2) to (T/2), and the FT resulted in a sinc function as sin(pifT) / (pifT), which is a real number, but the DFT resulted in (1 - e^(-i2pik)) / (1 - e^(-i2pik/N)).
The values for FT and DFT should be the same, so I would appreciate if you could tell me why this happened or where I went wrong in my approach.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Key Point:
You can expand out your ratio as a geometric series. The non-real summands will come in conjugate pairs, $\zeta$ and $\overline{\zeta}$, which will sum to a real number, $2 \cdot \mathfrak{Re}(\zeta)$. This is easy to see by graphing the summands as points.
More specifically, you are summing up the $N$th roots of unity, but with their argument scaled by a factor $k$ (or rather, the roots are raised to a power $k$).

So you have the quantity
$$
\frac{1 - e^{-2 i \pi k}}{1 - e^{-2 i \pi k/N}} \tag{1}
$$
Just by its appearance, it to me begs for a geometric series expansion:
$$
\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r} = \sum_{j=0}^n r^j
$$
Apply this for
$$
r := \exp \left( - \frac{2 \pi i k}{N} \right)
$$
Then
$$
\frac{1 - e^{-2 i \pi k}}{1 - e^{-2 i \pi k/N}}
= \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \exp \left( - \frac{2 \pi i kj}{N} \right) \tag{2}
$$
If $k$ is a multiple of $N$, then this summation is just summing up $e^{2\pi i \ell}$ for the integer $\ell = -j$, so it evaluates to just $N$. Notice that, in this scenario, appealing to $(1)$ would be troublesome: the denominator would be zero! Hence the appeal to $(2)$.
Otherwise, certainly $k$ is an integer regardless. For that case, appealing to $(1)$ is a nonissue, but then $e^{-2\pi ik} = (e^{2\pi i})^{-k}$ on top would evaluate to $1$, and the fraction to $0$. Thus your quantity desired is
$$
\begin{cases}
0, & N \mid k \\
n, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

That said, I'm not sure why you think this should result in a sinc function. Bear in mind the DFT is applied to sequences of numbers (e.g. sampled from a function) and returns a sequence, but the Fourier transform will apply to a suitable function and return another.

Your last paragraph is the key. "DFT" on a continuous function is not defined in usual sense and needs to be completely described.
